# Display number with 2 decimal place in Textbox by USING JQUERY

Tags: jquery, decimalformat

This my text box

```
asp:TextBox  ID="CurrentRateIDTextBox" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox
```

How to display Number with **2 decimal place** in Textbox by USING `JQUERY` Please give me full code. I am beginner.

Thank you

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Then update question with proper details so people don't have to guess what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is an `<input>` element of type number.

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" value="10.14">
```

This would allow you to enter numbers up to 2 decimal places. I think, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: That's exactly I am looking for.Thank you so much.